# How can I run a kvm guest without a framebuffer device?

Tags: virtualization, debian, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization

I have Win2008 on a Debian using kvm and it works beautifully with

```
kvm -m 2048 -vnc :0 win2008.img
```

Unfortunately it does not work when I remove the `-vnc :0` parameter:

```
kvm -m 2048 win2008.img
     =======================|  DirectFB 1.0.1  |=======================
          (c) 2001-2007  The DirectFB Organization (directfb.org)
          (c) 2000-2004  Convergence (integrated media) GmbH
        ------------------------------------------------------------

(*) DirectFB/Core: Single Application Core. (2008-08-17 14:50)
(*) Direct/Memcpy: Using libc memcpy()
(!) Direct/Util: opening '/dev/fb0' and '/dev/fb/0' failed
    --> No such file or directory
(!) DirectFB/FBDev: Error opening framebuffer device!
(!) DirectFB/FBDev: Use 'fbdev' option or set FRAMEBUFFER environment variable.
(!) DirectFB/Core: Could not initialize 'system' core!
    --> Initialization error!
Could not initialize SDL - exiting
```

Is there a way to run this without running a vnc server?

Answer (score 4):

try -nographic

all hail the almighty 'man'!